# Kafka connect with ibm-messaging connector not ingesting data into postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to ingest data from kafka-topic to postgres. I have successfully connected kafka and postgres through ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink connector.Below is my jdbc-sink-connector file:

```
name=jdbc-sink-connector1
connector.class=com.ibm.eventstreams.connect.jdbcsink.JDBCSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

# Below is the postgresql driver
driver.class=org.postgresql.Driver

# The topics to consume from - required for sink connectors
topics=connector7

# Configuration specific to the JDBC sink connector.
# We want to connect to a SQLite database stored in the file test.db and auto-create tables.
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/abc
connection.user=xyz
connection.password=***
connection.ds.pool.size=5
connection.table=company
insert.mode.databaselevel=true
put.mode=insert
table.name.format=company

auto.create=true
```

Now in kafka-producer I am sending data as follows:

```
{"schema": 
{"type": "struct","fields": [
{ "field": "id", "type": "integer", "optional": false },
{ "field": "time", "type": "timestamp", "optional": false },
{ "field": "name", "type": "string", "optional": false },
{ "field": "company", "type": "string", "optional": false }]},
"payload": 
{"id":"1",
"time":"2022-02-08 16:18:00-05",
"name":"ned",
"company":"advice"}}
```

It is giving the following error:

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-sink-connector1-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: 1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:607)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-sink-connector1-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:184)
```

Now according to my understanding I think there is some problem in my JSON in the way I am giving data to the producer but cannot seem to figure what it is?

Comment: 1) What converters are you using? 2) `integer` and `timestamp` are not valid JSON types for the schema. Where did you refer to those from? Looks like you put Avro types for the JSON types?

Comment: I followed this blog https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/kafka-postgres-connector-pipeline-series-part-6/ thats where I got the idea to write JSON in the specified format

Comment: id                     | numeric
time                 | timestamp with time zone
 name               | text
 company         | text


this is my targeted table and its columns datatypes.

Comment: 1) That link shows float32, not integer. The correct type for integers is `int32`. I'm not sure about timestamps, but an enum by that type is not in the JSONConverter source code. 2) I assume you do have `value.converter.schemas.enable=true`? 3) Is there more to the stacktrace than just two lines?

Comment: Thanks, its now working by changing datatype.